# PhpSpreadsheet's and PHP 7 > ZipArchive::close failure to create tempory file

Tags: php-7, phpspreadsheet

At work, we use PhpSpreadsheet to generate some Excel file (we use it to be able to provide some export).

Here is the simple code I use (based on some example given but PhpSpreadsheet) to generate a file:

```php
<?php

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;

include_once '../../../libs/includes.inc';

/** @var array $_POST */
$_POST = db::encodeHTMLPost($_POST);

/** @var string $httpReferer */
$httpReferer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if (strstr($httpReferer, '?')) {

    $httpReferer = explode('?', $httpReferer);
    $httpReferer = $httpReferer[0];
}

try {

    /** @var Spreadsheet $spreadsheet */
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();


//$spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();

// Set the document properties
    $spreadsheet
        ->getProperties()
        ->setCreator('Christina')
        ->setLastModifiedBy('Christina')
        ->setTitle('Test XLSX')
        ->setSubject('Here is the test')
        ->setDescription('Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.')
        ->setKeywords('office 2007 openxml php')
        ->setCategory('Test result file');

    $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('B2', 'World')
        ->setCellValue('C1', 'Here')
        ->setCellValue('D2', 'test');

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('A simple test');

    $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Xlsx)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
    header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0


    $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save('php://output');

    exit;

} catch (Exception $e) {

    var_dump($e);
}
```

Unfortunately, it returns an error in the generate Excel file:

**Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bdoparticipantenweekend.nl/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx.php on line 409**

I understand the error, I just don't know how to fix it.
I'm the only one to have this error at the office, of course.. I'm the only one to use PHP 7

I made some research, apparently PHP 7 as another behaviour about Zip::close(): https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.close.php#119960

Is somebody have a clue how to fix this ?

NB: PhpSpreadsheet is update at the version 1.8.2 (the latest one)

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong or you have not the permission to write into the path. Change the destination path or the permissions.